# Cannot log in via Facebook after logging in via Google

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to implement a 2-providers (Facebook & Google) login activity using Firebox. I've tested this system with the following scenarios, logging out is done by a single button which calls the `signOut()` method defined below:

1. Log in w/ Facebook, log out, log in w/ Facebook again.
2. Log in w/ Facebook, log out, log in w/ Google.
3. Log in w/ Google, log out, log in w/ Google again.
4. Log in w/ Google, log out, log in w/ Facebook again.

Scenarios 1-3 are succesful, but when I try to logging in with Google, logging out and then logging in with Facebook, I get a `ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL` error in the `onComplete` method of the `OnCompleteListener` in the `handleFacebookAccessToken` method. It's strange that this only happens after signing in with Google, I suspect that I am not implementing the log out mechanism for Google properly.

My main acitivity is as follows, the layout file is not specified as it is quite long, however View names are self-explanitory:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SKPrepareMapTextureListener, UpdateDbTask.UpdateDbTaskListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(Constants.defaultWebClientId)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);


    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_sign_in_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "facebook:onError", error);
        }
    });
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(Constants.APP_NAME, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Logged in with facebook.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}


public void signOut() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

    // Google sign out
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "signed out from google " + status.getStatusMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.google_sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;

    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);
    } else {
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:"
                            + task.isSuccessful());
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(Constants.APP_NAME, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Logged in with google",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Log attached:

```
10-05 16:09:23.243 4454-4454/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
10-05 16:09:23.403 29999-30148/? E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed com.android.vagabond
10-05 16:09:24.020 31516-31516/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.asus.filemanager-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.asus.filemanager-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
10-05 16:09:24.027 31516-31516/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.asus.filemanager-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.asus.filemanager-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
10-05 16:09:24.388 29999-31493/? E/IntentOperationSvc: Failed to instantiate Chimera operation impl, dropping operation
10-05 16:09:24.516 10694-10694/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bo.a(836): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
10-05 16:09:24.937 4454-4454/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
10-05 16:09:24.937 4454-4454/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
10-05 16:09:27.092 31501-31501/com.android.vagabond E/DB created: false
10-05 16:09:30.179 31501-31501/com.android.vagabond E/DB Hash request error: Cannot connect to Internet...
10-05 16:09:39.153 31643-31643/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.asus.filemanager-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.asus.filemanager-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
10-05 16:09:57.964 4454-4454/? E/ChimeraSrvcProxy: Can't find Chimera service impl class com.google.android.gms.clearcut.service.VacuumChimeraService
10-05 16:09:57.964 4454-4454/? E/ChimeraSrvcProxy: Proxy without impl dropping onStart()
10-05 16:09:59.822 29725-29733/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@c542d0b)
10-05 16:10:11.388 29725-29733/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@6a8d766)
10-05 16:10:32.541 31501-31831/com.android.vagabond E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

10-05 16:05:19.890 28275-28275/? D/com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: To set source application the context of activateApp must be an instance of Activity
10-05 16:10:31.929 861-13544/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK cmp=com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (has extras)} from uid 10114 on display 0
10-05 16:10:32.612 861-881/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity: +670ms
10-05 16:10:36.075 861-881/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
10-05 16:10:43.266 861-881/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
10-05 16:10:44.229 861-4529/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
10-05 16:10:44.251 861-26457/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
10-05 16:10:44.312 31501-31501/com.android.vagabond D/Vagabond: facebook:onSuccess:com.facebook.login.LoginResult@96a98e4
10-05 16:10:44.312 31501-31501/com.android.vagabond D/Vagabond: handleFacebookAccessToken:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, contact_email, email]}
10-05 16:10:54.311 861-26455/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.vagabond/com.facebook.FacebookActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193
```

Comment: do you have any message or log?

Comment: @JoséCarlos Of course, sorry, I've added logs. Also, I don't have a `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` Activity, is this in any way relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/liu/firebase-talk/ms_NVQem_Cw/8g7BFk1IAAAJ It explains why this happens. This is due to some security issue with Google emails being verified whereas Facebook emails are not.

Comment: The issue described in the thread mentions a scenario identical to mine, it does account for the issue but it doesn't really offer a solution, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question but are you aware of [Firebase UI Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md)? Its handling merging accounts for my app currently, and the repo is maintained by firebase and the community.

Comment: Not aware of it, but in any case, currently I'm not really keen to add yet another 3rd party library into my app

Comment: It's hosted under firebase's official GitHub. I'd personally recommend it as there is a lot of additional things to think about and test (Google smart lock on android for example) (replicating the same thing in iOS if you decide to develop on iOS). If you still prefer to rebuild the wheel, you could atleast reference their repo to see how they did it. Best of luck 